# After upgrading to Webpack version, new errors in my angular-cli app

Tags: angular-cli

I had an Angular2 app that ran. Then after upgrading it to the webpack version, I'm getting some errors mostly related to not being able to find things. My repository is [here](https://github.com/dancancro/bernierebuttals).

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md). Then after getting a warning that it couldn't find typings.json, I created a brand new app, made my package.json look more like its and redid node_modules/

What could be the problem?

```
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
*
*
 NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200.
*
8434ms building modules
11ms sealing
0ms optimizing
0ms basic module optimization
9ms module optimization
0ms advanced module optimization
25ms basic chunk optimization
0ms chunk optimization
1ms advanced chunk optimization
0ms module and chunk tree optimization
88ms module reviving
2ms module order optimization
4ms module id optimization
6ms chunk reviving
0ms chunk order optimization
26ms chunk id optimization
30ms hashing
1ms module assets processing
88ms chunk assets processing
4ms additional chunk assets processing
0ms recording
0ms additional asset processing
150ms chunk asset optimization
1422ms asset optimization
82ms emitting
Hash: deabe28457c8cb0333ca
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.18
Time: 10400ms
              Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     main.bundle.js   2.8 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
polyfills.bundle.js   220 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  polyfills
          inline.js  4.96 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
           main.map  3.33 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
      polyfills.map   300 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  polyfills
         inline.map  5.13 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
         index.html   1.1 kB          [emitted]

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
Cannot find source file '../src/index.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/index.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib'
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 14:18-38
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/angular-sortablejs/index.js
Cannot find source file 'index.ts': Error: Can't resolve './index.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/angular-sortablejs'
 @ ./src/app/+list/list.component.ts 13:27-56
 @ ./src/app/+list/list.routes.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.routes.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/dev-tools.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/components/dev-tools.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/components/dev-tools.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/components'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js 4:18-51
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/components/ng-redux.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/components/ng-redux.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/components'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js 2:17-49
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/decorators/select.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/decorators/select.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/decorators/select.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/decorators'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js 6:15-45
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/angular-sortablejs/src/sortable.directive.js
Cannot find source file 'sortable.directive.ts': Error: Can't resolve './sortable.directive.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/angular-sortablejs/src'
 @ ./~/angular-sortablejs/index.js 2:27-62
 @ ./src/app/+list/list.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/+list/list.routes.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.routes.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/shallow-equal.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/shallow-equal.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/shallow-equal.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 23:22-55
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/wrap-action-creators.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/wrap-action-creators.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/wrap-action-creators.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 24:29-69
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/type-checks.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/type-checks.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/type-checks.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 25:20-51
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/omit.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/omit.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/omit.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 26:13-37
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/invariant.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/invariant.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/invariant.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 27:18-47
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

WARNING in ./~/ng2-redux/lib/utils/get-in.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/utils/get-in.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../../src/utils/get-in.ts' in '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/utils'
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js 28:15-41
 @ ./~/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in [default]
File '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-toasty/src/toasty.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

ERROR in [default]
File '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-toasty/src/toasty.config.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

ERROR in [default]
File '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-toasty/src/toasty.container.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

ERROR in [default]
File '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/ng2-toasty/src/toasty.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts:81:34
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts:34:32
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts:11:16
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts:12:16
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts:68:58
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:9:13
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:15:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:16:37
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:34
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:92
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:33
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:49
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:148
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts:20:42
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts:41:37
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:79:87
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:137:41
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:196:32
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:24:14
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:26:15
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:115:122
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:115:164
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts:34:32
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:1:24
Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:2:24
Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:4:26
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:4:38
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:7:8
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:8:29
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts:11:42
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:11:16
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:12:16
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:68:58
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:9:13
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:15:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:16:37
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:34
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:92
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:33
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:49
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:148
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts:20:42
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:13:58
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts:9:57
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts:13:48
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts:61:147
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts:102:143
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts:107:138
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts:108:134
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts:18:52
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts:26:52
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/async.d.ts:34:32
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:9:13
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:15:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:16:37
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:34
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:92
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:33
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:49
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:148
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/facade/promise.d.ts:20:42
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts:45:58
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts:46:15
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts:81:89
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts:85:98
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts:89:98
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts:96:41
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts:17:36
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts:34:32
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:1:24
Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:2:24
Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:4:26
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:4:38
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:7:8
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:8:29
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:11:42
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:12:26
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:14:22
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:15:24
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:100:40
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:101:21
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts:102:24
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts:11:16
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts:12:16
Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts:68:58
Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:9:13
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:15:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:16:37
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:34
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:17:92
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:33
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:18:49
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:31
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:19:148
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts:20:42
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts:32:64
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts:40:55
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/service_message_broker.d.ts:35:83
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/worker/location_providers.d.ts:21:85
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:188:42
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:204:58
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:10:65
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:59
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:69
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:7:58
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:7:68
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:9:8
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:10:25
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:10:35
Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src/app/app.module.ts:1:9
Module '"/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported mng 'BrowserModule'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src/app/app.module.ts:2:9
Module '"/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported mng 'NgModule'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src/app/app.module.ts:3:9
Module '"/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/common/index"' has no exported mng 'CommonModule'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/src/app/app.module.ts:4:9
Module '"/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/bernierebuttals/node_modules/@angular/forms/index"' has no exported mng 'FormsModule'.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  3.05 kB       0
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you followed the upgrade instructions so I hope this helps: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md

Comment: Yes. Those are the instructions I followed.

Comment: Did you fixed your issue ?

Comment: No. I abandoned that project. Now I'm working on another angular-cli project and not having the problem.